# How to avoid writing this all the time in Scala?

Tags: scala

I often find myself writing this and I don't like it. Alternatives?

```
val b = {
  val a = getA()
  println(a)
  a
}
```

what I hate is having to assign a just to use it (not necessarily with a println, but with any function I don't care about the result)

Comment: I would prefer to keep your function pure function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly one of the use cases of `Scala 2.13`'s new [`tap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#tap[U](f:A=%3EU):A) chaining operation:

```
import util.chaining._

// def getA() = 43
val b = getA().tap(println)
// 43
// b: Int = 43
```

The [`tap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#tap[U](f:A=%3EU):A) chaining operation applies a side effect (in this case `println`) on a value (in this case the value returned by `getA()`: `43`) while returning this value unmodified:

> def tap[U](f: (A) => U): A

Answer (score 3):

Something like this maybe?

```
implicit class DebugTrace[A](value: A) {
  def trace[U](sideEffectyFunction: A => U): A = {
    sideEffectyFunction(value)
    value 
  }
}
```

If this is in scope, you get the method `trace` on everything. This method runs the argument function on the value, and then returns the value.

For example,

```
42 trace println
```

prints `42` and produces `42`.

---

It works with more complex blocks too (example REPL interaction):

```
scala> 42 trace { a =>
     |   println(s"The value of the constant 42 is = $a")
     |   println(s"And the square is = ${a * a}")
     | }
The value of the constant 42 is = 42
And the square is = 1764
res4: Int = 42
```

---

Similarly:

```
def getA(): Int = 42
val b = getA() trace println
```

prints the output of `getA()` and sets `b` to `42`.

A better question would be: why on earth do you want to contaminate any computations with `println` side-effects anyway? Looking at `println`'s not how you ensure that your code works correctly (even though I admit that it might be helpful to visualize some convoluted mutually recursive algorithms, for example).

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
def callReturn[A](value: A, f: A => Unit): A = {
    f(value)
    value
}

val b = callReturn(getA(), println)
```

And then you can define trace like:

```
def trace[A](value: A): A = callReturn(value, println)

val b = trace(getA())
```